# AverageIf and Multiple data strings

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-statements

I'm involved with a youth football tournament on the referee side, with assessing/coaching the referees. I've just taken over doing the data entry for the referees assessment scores which we then use to determine who gets finals etc and am looking to extract more usable information from the data to help us identify trends.

I've got (up to) 200 referees, each receiving from none to two assessment scores each day for 5 days. The scores are entered as both the raw mark and the weighted mark based on match difficulty (along with a host of other data about the match that isn't relevant to this issue.

I can extract the average mark (raw and weighted) across all referees without issues and have done so using the below formula, which is the raw average mark:

```
=AVERAGE(Working!AK4:AK200,Working!BK4:BK200,Working!CL4:CL200,Working!DL4:DL200,Working!EM4:EM200,Working!FM4:FM200,Working!GN4:GN200,Working!HN4:HN200,Working!IO4:IO200,Working!JO4:JO200)
```

But I also want to extract the average mark (raw and weighted) across two subsets - Academy and non academy referees, to help plot trends and determine where resources need to be utilised.

I've attempted to use an `AVERAGEIF` formula, but am getting a `#VALUE!` return. This is the formula that I've attempted to use to return the average raw mark for those referees in the academy:

```
=AVERAGEIF(Working!G4:G200,Working!G4:G200="Yes",(Working!AK4:AK200,Working!BK4:BK200,Working!CL4:CL200,Working!DL4:DL200,Working!EM4:EM200,Working!FM4:FM200,Working!GN4:GN200,Working!HN4:HN200,Working!IO4:IO200,Working!JO4:JO200))
```

If I do the same formula as above, but without the brackets around the [average_range], I get a 'you've used too many arguments, and it highlights BK200.

From what I've been able to find so far online, it seems that the formula I'm trying to use would only work if ALL the cells in `(Working!G4:G200)` returned "Yes". However if there are only 50 academy referees as indicated by "Yes" in G column, then I want those specific scores to be averaged, and the inverse for the non-academy referees.

I thought about having another sheet, which would simply contain populate from Column G (a simple =G4 and then populated down to =G200 next to all of the scores), consolidated into a block of raw marks columned under Assessment 1, 2, 3, 4.... and then the same for all of the weighted marks which would populate from the equivalent cell on the working sheet, but there's a lot of filtering, and re-sorting that goes on on the working sheet, and I'm not 100% certain that that wouldn't cause issues.

Any feedback on how to work through this problem, so that I can display the overall average mark for academy and non-academy referees in both raw and weighted form would be much appreciated, and I apologize if this post is rather convoluted.

Comment: Do you have any missing values in the scores or are they all filled in? Is it possible to have a score of zero?

Comment: Hi Tom, we only input a score if an assessment is completed, so yes, there are lots of missing values. It's possible to have a score of zero, but incredibly unlikely. I think the lowest I've seen is a 4...essentially anything below 5 is a fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a neat solution if the scores are in several columns which are not consecutive.

My suggestion is:-

(1) Work out the sum for each column separately and total them up

(2) Work out the count for each column separately and total them up

(3) Divide Sum by Count to get Average.

In my small example below with 3 referees and 3 columns:-

(1) In K2:-

```
=SUMIF(H2:H4,"Yes",B2:B4)+SUMIF(H2:H4,"Yes",D2:D4)+SUMIF(H2:H4,"Yes",F2:F4)
```

(2) In K3:-

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B4,">=0",H2:H4,"Yes")+COUNTIFS(D2:D4,">=0",H2:H4,"Yes")+COUNTIFS(F2:F4,">=0",H2:H4,"Yes")
```

(3) In K4:

```
=K2/K3
```

This would include any zero scores (if this is possible) but exclude any blanks.

You can then scale it up to your data.

[image]

Beyond this, you would have to change the data structure either

(1) Add a row to label the columns that you want to average e.g.

```
Score 1 Score 2 Score 3
3       0       3
```

so you could pick up only the columns labelled 3 say

Here's how it would be in my small example:-

In K3:-

```
=SUM((B$2:F$2=3)*($H3:$H5="Yes")*B3:F5)
```

Which is an array formula and must be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

In K4:-

```
=SUM((B$2:F$2=3)*($H3:$H5="Yes")*(B3:F5<>""))
```

another array formula

In K5:-

=K3/K4

This is how the columns you want are labelled with a 3 in row 2, so it ignores the other columns:-

[image]

(2) Consolidate them into another sheet as you suggest.